# Making cheese without rennet

Tags: cheese-making, mozzarella

What can I use in place of rennet to make mozzarella cheese? And what cheeses can we make without rennet?

Comment: Why are you avoiding rennet? (Knowing that will help us recommend replacements that do suit you.)

Comment: Because I can't buy rennet in my country.

Comment: even in an online shop? or even imported?

Comment: That seems ... unlikely?  Does nobody make cheese in your country?  Does nobody slaughter goats?

Comment: It's normal. My grandparents never ate cheese until I bought them some. As far as I know, all kinds of cheese products sold in our supermarkets are imported. I just want to find a way to make cheese at home to reduce costs since I'm living in the countryside and shipping fees are expensive.

Comment: Huh.  What country to you live in? I'm wondering about getting it from a neighboring country you can have stuff shipped from.  Rennet keeps for a really long time in the fridge, like years, so if you can get one 4oz bottle you're set for a long time.

Comment: The other option, if you're living in the countryside, is to try to get a piece of raw calf's stomach or kid's stomach, which is where we get rennet from in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot make mozzarella without some form of rennet.  It can be natural rennet, synthetic, or vegetable-based rennet, but you need it to get the correct cheese texture.

This goes for the vast majority of cheeses.  The only ones you can make without any type of rennet are the soft, heat-and-acid-set cheeses such as ricotta, farmer cheese, chevre, and paneer.